# Proof for linear algebra theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove that if $AB=cI$ for some matrices $A,\ B$ and number $c$, then $AB = BA$. 
I start my proof with $c \neq 0$. then, $A$ and $B$ are invertible, And $BA = B(cB^{-1}) = cBB^{-1} = cI = AB.$ 
What about $c = 0$?
I guess it's true, but i'm not sure. If I true for $c = 0$, what is the proof? If It's not, what is the contradiction example?
Thank you.

Comment: I guess $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, otherwise it isn't even true for $c=1$.

Comment: You may attract more attention to your question by changing the title to explain what theorem you want to prove.

Comment: The above representation isn't a theorem. A know linear algebra theorem is: if $AB=BA$ for every $N$ by $N$ matrix $A$, then $B=cI$ for some constant $c$.

Answer (score 3):

If $c=0$, the statement is false. Take, for instance,$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$Then $AB=0$, but$$BA=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$